# Compare list values to a queryset field

Tags: python, django

I'm struggling to determine why my IF statement is failing.

I want to compare a list array to a database field, and when I find the match, I need to retrieve the list index number for future use. The database field must match an entry in the list as the Django model specifies the field is a lookup field.

The queryset for the master records is loading as expected.
the Status list is being built as expected.
When I do the comparison 'if val == d.stage:' it never returns as true.
what am I missing?

```
# read the database records (less than 100 records)
deal_set = Deal.objects.filter().order_by('stage__sort_order')

# build a list of all possible status records (there are only 10 records)
queryset = Status.objects.filter().order_by('sort_order')
stage_list = []
for q in queryset:
   stage_list.append(q.stage)

# loop through each master record
for d in deal_set:
   # loop through the list of stages and compare to the stage field in the master record
   for idx, val in enumerate(stage_list):
      if val == d.stage:
         stage_pos = idx
         break
```

the print statements show:

```
idx=0, val=LOI Submitted, d.stage=LOI Submitted, show on dashboard=None
idx=1, val=Active, d.stage=LOI Submitted, show on dashboard=None
idx=2, val=Live Deal, d.stage=LOI Submitted, show on dashboard=None
idx=3, val=New Deal, d.stage=LOI Submitted, show on dashboard=None
idx=4, val=IOI Submitted, d.stage=LOI Submitted, show on dashboard=None
idx=5, val=Pending, d.stage=LOI Submitted, show on dashboard=None
idx=6, val=Under Review, d.stage=LOI Submitted, show on dashboard=None
idx=7, val=Management Presentation, d.stage=LOI Submitted, show on dashboard=None
idx=8, val=Canceled, d.stage=LOI Submitted, show on dashboard=None
idx=9, val=Complete, d.stage=LOI Submitted, show on dashboard=None
```

The `models.py` file:

```
class Status(models.Model):
    stage = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    show_on_dashboard = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True,
        verbose_name="Show on Dashboard",
        max_length=3,
        choices=YorN
        )
    sort_order = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    def __str__(self):
        # return u'{0}'.format(self.stage)
        return u'{0}, show on dashboard={1}'.format(self.stage, self.show_on_dashboard)

class Deal(models.Model):
    deal_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    deal_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    short_description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    deal_description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    new_deal_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="New Deal Date")
    signed_nda = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True,
        verbose_name="Signed NDA",
        max_length=3,
        choices=YorN
        )
    # http://www.jeffreyteruel.com/article/42
    industry = models.ForeignKey(Industry, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    stage = models.ForeignKey(Status, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Could we see the models.py for Deal and Status. Have you tried adding print statements before the if statement to see what's actually being evaluated.

Before   ```if val == d.stage:``` add ```print(val, d.stage)``` to see what's being compared.

Comment: updated the problem ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line `if val == d.stage:` you are comparing a string (`val`) to a `Status` object (`d.stage`).

I suggest changing your code to compare the IDs of Status objects instead.

```
# read the database records (less than 100 records)
deal_qs = Deal.objects.order_by('stage__sort_order')

# build a list of all possible status records (there are only 10 records)
status_id_list = list(
    Status.objects.order_by('sort_order').values_list('id', flat=True))

# loop through each master record
for d in deal_qs:
   # loop through the list of status and compare to the stage/status field in the master record
   for i, status_id in enumerate(status_id_list):
      if status_id == d.stage_id:
         stage_pos = i
         break
```

This compares the field `Deal.stage_id` to the IDs in `status_id_list`.

---

Of course, you could also change your code to compare strings in both cases, but since the field `Status.stage` is not marked as unique, this is not optimal to use for comparisson.

Comment: using the id field solved the problem. thank for the assist!